# Can't use proxies from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can use proxies without a problem by doing

```
var proxies = fs.readFileSync('proxies.txt', 'utf-8').replace(/\r/gi, '').split('\n');
```

But when I do

```
(function scrapeProxies() {
request.get('https://mezy.wtf/proxies.txt', (err, res, body) => {
    proxies = body.split('\n');
    setTimeout(() => scrapeProxies(), 2 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

It doesn't seem to work no matter what I do, giving the error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

It'd be nice if someone could help me out as I'm very new to this, and just learning! It'd be very appreciative, Thanks.

Here's my code, as I can't upload here as it's too long for me to paste it all:

https://pastebin.com/raw/HNQYBXyG

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, based on your code

```
const scrapeProxies = () => {
        request.get('https://mezy.wtf/proxies.txt', (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            proxies = body.replace(/\r/gi, '').split('\n');
            setTimeout(() => scrapeProxies(), 2 * 60 * 1000);
        })
    };


scrapeProxies();
```

Your code has the following issues:

1st - You need to check if there are any errors in the request which is done with

```
if (err) throw err;
```

Which means if an error is found, it will throw an exception.

2nd - After you split by '\n' each string in the array still has '\r', that's why you need to replace it with nothing as you've done in the first example.

```
 body.replace(/\r/gi, '')
```

OR you could split by '\r\n' directly.

```
 body.split('\r\n');
```

Comment: Please, provide more context on why that code should work, teach the person don't just fix the issue

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your reply on my question. This indeed fixes the error that was recieved but now it's just stuck on the "Checking" part, and doesn't actually check. Do you know why this would be? I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Okay, great. It's checking the tokens, but it's only checking 1 every minute or so (used to check 500 a minute) any idea why this would be? Cheers